# Diferential equation with $\sinh$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, definite-integrals

I'm trying to solve the following differential equation for $z\in [0,\infty]$:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^{2}\phi}{\partial z^{2}}=A\sinh\left[B\phi\left(z\right)\right]
\end{equation}
with boundary condition $\phi(z=0)=W$ and $\frac{\partial\phi(z)}{\partial z}|_{z\rightarrow \infty} = 0$.
I started solving this by multiplying both sides by $\frac{\partial\phi(z)}{\partial z}$ and integrating in z. This gave me

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z}\right)^{2}=\frac{1}{B}\cosh\left[B\phi\left(z\right)\right]+C
\end{equation}

However, I have no idea how to proceed from here. I initially thought about squaring everything, but it seems only more complicate to integrate $\sqrt{\cosh[] + C}$. Any ideas?

Thanks!

I have a book that says there is a closed analytical formula for that
[image]

Comment: You can solve for the derivative in your second equation as $$\frac{d\phi}{dz}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{B}\cosh(B\phi(z))+2C}.$$ At that point, you can instead consider $z$ as a function of $\phi$ and therefore write $$\frac{dz}{d\phi}=\pm\left(\frac{2}{B}\cosh(B\phi)+2C\right)^{-1/2}$$ which is separable. So you can antidifferentiate both sides to get $$z(\phi)=\int^\phi \frac{dz}{\sqrt{\text{horrid stuff}}}.$$ One then does one's best to invert that relationship again. This is the same technique used to analytically solve the mathematical pendulum.

Comment: @Semiclassical I've just added a photo of a book that claims there is analytical solution for this problem. Do you have comment on that?

Comment: This appears to be the ["high-potential case"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%E2%80%93Boltzmann_equation#High-potential_case) discussed in Wikipedia's page for the Poisson-Boltzmann equation. As it stands, though, I'm nonplussed as to  how that could possibly solve the stated ODE analytically. Edit: Following up on the Wikipedia page gives a textbook source for the derivation ([source](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Physics_and_Chemistry_of_Interfaces/-28DDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=physics%20and%20chemistry%20of%20interfaces&pg=PA62&printsec=frontcover)).

Comment: To put a pin in this: The boundary conditions required are that both $\phi(z)$ and $\phi'(z)$ vanish as $z\to\infty$. Hence the integration constant isn't free but must equal $-1/B$, in which case the "horrid stuff' is actually nice enough to be give a solvable integral. (Also, the potential should decrease as $z\to\infty$ and therefore the negative square root will be the correct one.)

Comment: @Semiclassical Yeap, that is it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with the equation
$$\frac{d^{2}\phi}{dz^{2}}=A\sinh\left(B\phi\right)$$ switch variables to get
$$-\frac{z''}{[z']^3}=A\sinh\left(B\phi\right)$$ So, reduction of order $(p=z')$
$$-\frac{p'}{p^3}=A\sinh\left[B\phi\right]\implies p=\pm\frac{\sqrt{B}}{\sqrt{2A \cosh (B \phi)+k_1}}$$ The problem is that now we shall face elliptic integrals.

Before any simplification (still ignoring the signs of $A$, $B$ and $k_1$
$$z+c_2=\pm\frac{2 i \sqrt{\frac{2 A \cosh (B \phi)+k_1}{2 A+k_1}}}{\sqrt{B} \sqrt{2 A \cosh (B
   \phi)+k_1}}\, F\left(i\frac{ B \phi}{2}|\frac{4 A}{2 A+k_1}\right)$$

Inversing the monster would not be very pleasant.